# How to make QPushButtons to add text into QLineEdit box in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

I was making a password window.
Raspberry to use on touch screen
but I'm in trouble now

I want to add the characters that fit the clicked QPushbutton to QLineEdit
but I don't know way that can solve this problem

please help me

I tried this code

```py
self.pb_1.clicked.connect(self.AddOne)

@pyqtSlot()
def AddOne(self)
   self.tbx_pw.text += "1"
```

i want add the characters but 
this code kill process

Comment: Try it change `self.tbx_pw.text += "1"` to `self.tbx_pw.setText("{}".format(self.tbx_pw.text() + "1"))`

Comment: It does very well as you say. Thank you